# How far does the power of the Talosians extend?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In the two-parter The Menagerie the Commodore Mendez on board the Enterprise is revealed to be an illusion.

There is, however, also a real Commodore Mendez on Starbase 6.

So when Kirk leaves with Mendez to go after the rogue Enterprise, we have to conclude we're already seeing the mirage. But this would imply that the Talosian's powers reach to Starbase 6 itself.

Is that meant to be implied?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We never see any real limits of the Talosians to project their illusions. Then again, Kirk is in too much of a hurry to catch the wayward Enterprise to seriously question why a Commodore would want to come along.

> MENDEZ: We coast.
>   KIRK: Blast you any way. You had no right to come along.
>   MENDEZ: RHIP, Captain. Rank hath its privileges.

So it's not implied they can reach that far with their illusion powers, it's simple fact.

Answer (score 13):

In a discarded line from the original script, Vina implies that their reach really has no limits (Much like the Q).

From the Memory Alpha on the Talosians (Emphasis mine):

> In a line of dialogue which was scripted for "The Cage" but not included in the final version of that episode (nor any other installment), Pike commented, "What's happened to the Talosians could be sort of a warning, couldn't it. For us individually or for a whole race. Our electronic tape, our viewing screens, even our books, must never become a substitute for real life." In another scripted but discarded line, Vina said of the Talosians, "***Since their minds can reach anywhere***, most of them are like cocoons or larvae now. They just sit and let the thought records or some specimen live for them. Some of them hardly move, except to take that blue protein once a day."

Comment: Which then raises the question of why the prohibition on visiting Talos exists. They're just as dangerous if you don't actually go there.

Comment: @Barmar: Please do actually ask the question :)

Comment: I seriously doubt that the Talosians could cause an Ocampa in the Delta Quadrant to see things.

Comment: All would be explained if you could assume that the Talosians could use people with whom they've had direct contact (Spock and Pike) as conduits to influence the minds of people further away-- perhaps only if the conduits already had ESP (like Spock) and were willing.

Comment: @Barmar The prohibition would exist because visiting their planet will draw their attention.

Comment: @Bamar I actually asked this question to be able to ask that next, but the other question got closed. (
About Starfleet's knowledge about the Talosians) Maybe you can ask it better?

Comment: @antlersoft That's what I always assumed. They are not omniscient and their powers are in creating illusions, as in affecting minds, so they would need to be aware of someone to play their tricks on them.